# How run sql server script and save it to mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a script sql exported from sql server. I would like run this script and save it on a mysql data base or other kind of database, copy all the tables, the primary and foreign keys etc.
Thanks in advance for help me.

Comment: When you mean save do you mean that you want to import the exported sql script into a new mysql instance?

Comment: [Guide to Migrating from Microsoft SQL Server to MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/white-papers/guide-to-migrating-from-sql-server-to-mysql/)

Comment: yes, just that, "copy" all database schema to new mysql instance. Thanks i will read through migration guide.